# Hot delete all html except image?

Tags: php

Good day.

I have html:

```
<p>fsfsf</p>
<p>tgff</p>
<p><img src="../243234345/Desert.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" /></p>
<p>asasdasdasd</p>
<p>asdas</p>
<p>d</p>
<p>asdasdsadsad</p>
<p>sad</p>
```

Tell me please how remove all html except image (except line `<img ... />`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `strip_tags('your html', 'img');`

Syntax: `string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )`

Ref: https://www.php.net/strip_tags

Comment: oh, I forgot about it) thanks. i accept after 11 minutes(rules stack)

Answer (score 0):

```
var keep = [];
$('img').each(function(i,elem) {
    keep.push(elem.outerHTML);
});
$('body').empty();
console.dir(keep);

$.each(keep,function(i,elem){
    $('body').append(elem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do this for each line ($string).

```
<?php
$string = "<p>fsfsf</p>";
$output = ereg_replace('<p>(?!<img).*</p>', '\\0', $string);
echo $output; 
?>
```